# Can't get Video details through Facebook Marketing API despite of having all necessary permissions

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-marketing-api

I try to get video details from my Creative through Facebook Marketing API.

Here is my code:

```
 Api::init(
     env('ADS_APP_ID'),
     env('ADS_APP_SECRET'),
     env('ADS_ACCESS_TOKEN')
 );

 $account = new AdAccount(env('ADS_ACCOUNT_ID'));
 $adcreatives = $account->getAdCreatives(array(
     AdCreativeFields::VIDEO_ID,
 ));

 $video_id = $adcreatives[0]->{AdCreativeFields::VIDEO_ID};

 $ad_video = new AdVideo($video_id);
 dd($ad_video->getSelf([AdVideoFields::THUMBNAILS]));
```

Also I have added necessary permissions in my App and double checked everything, I have:

- pages_read_engagement - Standart Access
- Page Public Content Access - Standart Access

Every seems fine and it should work, but I am getting this error:

FacebookAds\Http\Exception\AuthorizationException
(#10) This endpoint requires the 'pages_read_engagement' permission or the 'Page Public Content Access' feature. Refer to https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review/login-permissions#manage-pages and https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review/feature#reference-PAGES_ACCESS for details.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by _“have added necessary permissions in my App”_? What is `ADS_ACCESS_TOKEN` supposed to be here, which _type_ of token?

Comment: Actually I don't know which type it is, but I generated it here: https://ibb.co/tcTYpH9, but yes I see, there is no those permissions which I need, and I don't have idea how to get more options there. But under this page, I can see, that I have Standard Access for pages_read_engagement https://ibb.co/PrMLddw

Comment: _“I can see, that I have Standard Access for pages_read_engagement”_ - that means, that your app is _allowed to_ request that permission from users. But that does not mean, any specific user would _have_ automatically granted it. If you can not select additional permissions in the place that your first screenshot show - then generate a user token in Graph API Explorer instead, or implement Facebook Login.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation, a little bit more clear now. Some clarifications: I have App which is associated with Business, and currently i am able to get Campaigns, Adsets and Ads data (probably cause of permission from first screenshot), and how I understand, i wont get access to Business accounts other data if I will generate token in Graph API Explorer. Or I am wrong?

Comment: I am expecting, that Business should allow my App to get access to their data, but I cant figure how they could give me this access.

Comment: A token is a token, it doesn’t matter where you create it, as long as it encompasses all the necessary permissions.

Comment: Are you explicitly talking about System Users in a Business Manager context here, most of those API requests will only require your standard user token, and those can be created in GAE or by implementing Facebook login in the absolutely usual way.

Comment: Thx a lot for your support. I generated user token through GAE with necessary permissions, and I was managed to get Video, but the token has been expired after couple of hours. But if I try to generate App token, empty popup appears and it redirects to same GAE page, but with selected User Token select option. I am creating web-based app, which will work standalone, and i cant use User token, and recreate it every couple of hours..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228000/discussion-between-aleksandrs-and-cbroe).

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/refreshing

Comment: Omg, thank you so much, i got Long-Lived User Access Token and everything is working like a charm. Have a nice weekend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After conversation with [@CBroe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1427878/cbroe) in comments section, I can summarise steps which I did to avoid that error message:

1. Navigate to [Graph API Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/)
2. Select your app in Facebook App select box
3. Select User token in User or Page select box
4. Add necessary permissions (in my case it was `pages_read_engagement`)
5. Press Generate Access Token button
6. Copy Token

Additionally if you want token, which will not expire in couple of hours, you can generate it here [Long-Lived User Access Token](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/refreshing)